# Pandoc Lua Program not parsing linebreaks in lists using Custom Lua for BBCode

Tags: lua, pandoc

I have source code that I use to convert docx files into BBCode, it is a lua file. It works mostly as intended, but there is an issue that I'm having trouble rectifying. When this code reaches a list, it skips over the blank spaces between the items, and truncates the entire list so that there are only single line breaks.

The current text is outputted like so:

```
[list][*][b]Testsadfasddf[/b]
[*][i]Sadfasdfgasdgf asf[/i]
[*][u]Asdgsdfgh[/u]
[*][i][b]Sdfgsdrhstreuj[/b][/i]
[*][b][u]Fsdfgsdfghsfghj[/u][/b]
[*][i][u]Sdfhserysrhfgh[/u][/i]
[*][i][b][u]sdfghsehjusrtu[/u][/b][/i]
[*][s]Sdfhstuikuftkl[/s]
[/list]
```

when it should have a line break between each item. Because I am using custom lua, I can not use the hard_line_break extension that was suggested, and since I'm not converting to markdown I have trouble finding help that is prevalent to me after searching.

```
local function listenclose(t, s, p)
  if p then
    return string.format("[%s]%s", t, p, s, t)
  else
    return string.format("[%s]%s", t, s, t)
  end
end



local function makelist(items)
  local buf = "[list]"
  for _,e in ipairs(items) do
    buf = buf .. listenclose('*', e) .. '\n'
  end
  buf = buf .. '[/list]'
  return buf
end



function BulletList(items)
  return makelist(items)
end
```

What do I need to add that would read the linebreaks properly? Or is it actually overtly complicated, and I won't be able to achieve this easily?

Comment: maybe not related to your problem but you only use 2 of the 3/4 values provided to string.format and string.format("[list]") can be replaced by "[list]"

Comment: Try replacing `\n` with `\n\n` in the code snippet.

Comment: I editted the code to reflect Piglet's suggestion, and tarleb while \n\n will produce two lines every time, it then gives me the opposite problem. I want it to account for both cases, but that might be much harder than I think it is.

Comment: I'd need more information on the problem. But a hacky solution I can think of is pre-process the file and replace the line breaks with a special sequence like 'LINEBRK123'. After all is done, you can use a lua script to delete all the special sequences and insert line breaks on the next lines.